# Bootstrap: In Navbar, Show Different Content Based on Li Link Hovered in a Single Location?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've tried a few JQuery and CSS implementations of this, but can't seem to get it quite right. I'm utilizing FontAwesome icons in the navbar for Bootstrap, and I would like to have a single location where, when the icons are hovered, a text description of them is shown/hidden.

This implementation has gotten me the farthest, with the different captions showing up. However, I need them all to appear in one location (preferably to the front of the ul navbar-nav grouping, as they will be right aligned).

CSS:

```
div#navbar a span {display: none;}

div#navbar a:hover span {display: block; position: absolute; top: 40px; left:-50px; width: 125px; padding: 5px; margin: 10px; z-index: 100;color: #AAA; background: black;font: 10px Verdana, sans-serif; text-align: center;}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#about" class="nav-button-bg nav1"><div class="nav-button"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></div><span>Text Goes Here</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="nav-button-bg nav2"><div class="nav-button"><i class="fa fa-umbrella"></i></div><span>Text Goes Here 2</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#about" class="nav-button-bg nav3"><div class="nav-button"><i class="fa fa-star"></i></div><span>Text Goes Here 3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

The implementation above is based off MeyerWeb's CSS Popup Demo

I have tried JQuery Fiddles that worked for simple classes/links such as this: http://jsfiddle.net/AstroCB/42gV5/ , but I'm uncertain if the depth of Bootstrap classes is causing some sort of override, as I cannot seem to get JQuery show/hide functions based on the examples I've seen to work.

I have also tried ~ relations such as: http://jsfiddle.net/YsHA4/ but am again hitting a wall.

It's highly likely I am just approaching this the wrong way, but I've been attempting to solve this problem for a few days now and just can't seem to find a solution. A fresh set of eyes and any and all help would be absolutely appreciated. If there's any way I can clarify, please let me know. Thank you!!

**EDITED TO ADD:** I do not need the final result to be spans inside the links in any regard, they can be hidden external divs, etc. The example I gave is the farthest I have managed to get the functionality to what I want (separate information showing up for each hover), but if a different approach using JS/etc removes the spans or hard codes the text into a JS string in some way, so be it. I am just looking to get this functionality to work as anticipated with Bootstrap, whatever implementation best gets it there!

Also, see my comment for an image representation of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: This is an example image of the look I am trying to achieve in the navbar: [link](http://i8.photobucket.com/albums/a7/vmk1991/bootstrapexample_zps4xhgqzkw.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5c1qLft/) based on your image.
It uses bootstraps right section for the menu.

I have applied a loop to each link:

```
$.each($('a'), function() {
    $(this).hover(function() {
        $('.placeholder').html($(this).html());
    });
});
```

It simply takes the HTML inside a  tag and places in the menu item with the class `placeholder`.

Update:

In your case your links are bit more complex so the selector for the loop would look like this:

```
$.each($('a > span'), function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

This fetches all links in your document and then the span element inside that.

Aaand finally a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5c1qLft/1/) for the HTML you have provided here.

Code below edited since loops are unecessary:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
    $('.placeholder').html($(this).html());
});

$('a > span').hover(function() {
    // do stuff here
});
```

Comment: This is so much closer than I was able to get - thank you for your help! Is there a way to ensure the span tag text is hidden in the original link, but still shows up in the placeholder? I'm currently working to edit the Fiddle for this, but perhaps you might have a quick insight. The spans of "Text Goes Here" I don't want showing up on the original links, only in the placeholder hover. I apologize if I didn't have that properly portrayed - it was what the Font Awesome classes were there to achieve. I'm looking for icons on the links, then text in the placeholder on hover of the icons.

Comment: @Briana [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/e5c1qLft/3/) is an example of that. I used the data-* attribute in HTML to store the text in the <a> tag and then fetch it with jquery. In the hover function you see two different functions, the top one is `mouseenter` and the bottom one is `mouseleave`.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for. I've selected your answer, thank you for taking the time to help me! I have one other question, mostly because I am still learning JavaScript. I am hoping that when I collapse the navbar, I can get the labels to appear in the menu alongside the icons, as on mobile the hover won't be available. I can likely use a media query to individually put each li's data-content alongside it in that mobile view right? Or would that be a bit more complex than I'm thinking?

Comment: I'm curious... why are you doing `$.each` instead of just `$('a > span').hover(...`?

Answer (score 1):

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="hover"><a href="#about" class="nav-button-bg nav1"><div class="nav-button"><i class="fa fa-user"></i><span class="text hidden"> Text Goes Here</span></div></a>

    </li>
    <li class="hover"><a href="#about" class="nav-button-bg nav2"><div class="nav-button"><i class="fa fa-umbrella"></i><span class="text hidden"> Text Goes Here 2</span></div></a>

    </li>
    <li class="hover"><a href="#about" class="nav-button-bg nav3"><i class="fa fa-star"></i> <span class="text hidden">Text Goes Here 2</span> </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.hover').each(function (index, el) {
        var thiz = $(this);
         var  text = thiz.find('.text');
        thiz.on('mouseover', function (e) {
            text.removeClass('hidden');
        });
        thiz.on('mouseleave', function(e){
            text.addClass('hidden')
        });
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsHA4/182/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This implementation actually encapsulates exactly what I'm hoping would happen in the mobile nav (icons/text appearing alongside each other when text is normally hidden otherwise). However for the desktop I am trying to implement that the labels all appear in the same location removed from the icons - a div/span to the left or right for example.